# Right align button within a div

Tags: html, css, layout

I a not very good at CSS, so I have a question for newbies. I have the following fragment of a html:

```html
<div _ngcontent-vyb-c4="" class="form-row">
   <div _ngcontent-vyb-c4="" class="col-md-12">
      <div _ngcontent-vyb-c4="" class="form-group">
         <h5 _ngcontent-vyb-c4="">Contract</h5>
         <button _ngcontent-vyb-c4="" class="buttons-form mat-mini-fab mat-button-base mat-primary" color="primary" mat-mini-fab="" type="button" ng-reflect-color="primary">
            <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
               <mat-icon _ngcontent-vyb-c4="" class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color" role="img" aria-hidden="true">settings</mat-icon>
            </span>
...
```

How to align the button with the icon on the right side of the h5, aligned at the far right. Here is a screenshot of the current layout. I want the gear icon and the button to be on the same row [image: Here is a screenshot of the current layout.] This is part of an Angular project as if this does matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to align the items very easily.

```css
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-vyb-c4="" class="form-row">
   <div _ngcontent-vyb-c4="" class="col-md-12">
      <div _ngcontent-vyb-c4="" class="form-group">
         <h5 _ngcontent-vyb-c4="">Contract</h5>
         <button _ngcontent-vyb-c4="" class="buttons-form mat-mini-fab mat-button-base mat-primary" color="primary" mat-mini-fab="" type="button" ng-reflect-color="primary">
            <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
               <mat-icon _ngcontent-vyb-c4="" class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color" role="img" aria-hidden="true">settings</mat-icon>
            </span>
...
```

Comment: I want the title and the button to be on the same row, just the button to be on the far right

Comment: Oh, ok, I misunderstood what you meant. I updated my answer accordingly. Just give the container a display: flex, justify-content: space-between and that should handle it for the most part.

Comment: That works but it drags the elements below the button. In this case it is a div with class="row". It floats to the right of the gear icon as well, which is undesired behavior in this case.